# Significance of Permutation Vector Ordering in QR Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, matrix-decomposition, svd

In the QR-decomposition of a matrix $\mathbf{U}^T$ with pivoting, the permutation matrix can be expressed as a vector that re-orders the columns of the matrix in a manner such that the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{R}$ are non-increasing.

If $\mathbf{U}$ is the left unitary matrix in a singular-value decomposition of $\mathbf{M}^T$, what information about the significance of the columns of $\mathbf{M}$ does this ordering provide?

Answer (score 0):

None. You will never pivot when you compute a QR factorization of a matrix which is already unitary. Hence the permutation matrix is *always* the identity matrix.

Comment: I know it is not necessary to pivot since the unitary matrix is not rank deficient.  However, if one does, the pivoting is done to make the absolute values of the diagonal elements in $\mathbf{R}$ non-increasing.  What do the results of that goal imply, if anything, about the corresponding columns of $\mathbf{M}$ ?

Comment: @BaronFiner  How will you decide which column of $U$
to pivot to the front when they all have the same norm? They are all equally good and you have no reason to prefer one over the other

Comment: My question was motivated by the algorithm discussed on pages 8 and 9 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00370.pdf).

Comment: @BaronFiner: The subject matter looks familiar, but it may well be a while before I have time to look at this. Try to express your thoughts and ideas as a small program which can be tested.